# matching file extension not working jQuery-

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, file-extension

I am checking file extension before uploading it to the server.

Using this Regex to check valid file extension-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#uploadBtn').change(function () {
            var ext = this.value.split('.').pop();
            var valid_extensions = /^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))+(.mp3|.MP3|.mpeg|.MPEG|.m3u|.M3U|.flv|.FLV|.mp4|.MP4|.wmv|.WMV|.webm|.WEBM|.3gp|.3GP|.swf|.SWF|.mov|.MOV|.mkv|.MKV|.mpeg|.MPEG)$/;
            if (valid_extensions.test(ext)) {
                alert('OK');
            }
            else {
                alert('Invalid File');
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

I am dropping file with extension `.mp4` in it therefor it should alert me `OK` but this query always shows me `Invalid File` alert.
In case of an Image file also it shows me `Invalid file` alert.

Is there any better regular extension for this or how do I modify this to working script.

Comment: You shouldn't use `alert` like a debugging tool, use `console.log`. If you need to pause execution, use a breakpoint in the development tools

Comment: Why use such a monstrous regex? It would be more readable by using arrays and simple logic.

Comment: Maintainability is over-rated

Answer (score 0):

this may work for u.I think it only checks for extension, try this once

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9])*\.(mp3|mp4|xls|jpeg)$/.test("asdf.mp3")
```

In the extension list add all your necessary extensions I added only few.